# predicting a real number in fixed range

Tags: regression

Suppose we need to predict a real number in fixed range, for example, [0 .. 5], and Y can be 3.14, 2.4654 etc.
What is the name of this kind of tasks (to be able to search further) and what are the approaches to solve this problem?
The only idea I got is to normalize Y to [0 .. 1] dividing by (max-min),
and then make some sort of maximum likelihood estimation, considering Y like a Probability, but we can get many features with a various PDFs, so the problem is to make choise of Y target pdf.

Comment: many people would use a Beta Regression for this.

Comment: If you know the range of the target variable, then you can normalize your data to $[0,1]$, then use beta regression.